# How do I close EventMachine.system's side of an stdin pipe?

Tags: ruby, unix, eventmachine

I've blanked entirely. When I run the following the program hangs indefinitely.

```
require 'eventmachine'

EM.run do

  EM.system '/usr/bin/md5sum', proc{ |p| p.send_data("hashme") } do |stdout, status|
    puts stdout
    EM.stop
  end

end
```

How do I send EOF to close up the stdin side of the pipe? I note that the [system documentation](http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine.html#M000329) cheats somewhat by feeding `exit` to `sh`. I'm using EM 0.12.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using master, or 0.12.? Use mast.r